# Posting data via JSON object using curl in the command line

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl, command-line

I am trying to post data from one server to another server via the command line. Eventually, I will use real data, but for now I just want to test that it works, which it doesn't.

In the command line for server1 I am using curl to send data via JSON and in my other server I have a method where I receive the JSON object, decode it and print it out, however here is where I have the problem.

Without sending a JSON object, everything works fine: I can print "sample sentence", which shows that my method is being reached and works.

However when I send a JSON object, it prints all of the details from my .env file, and nothing from the object I sent, which I don't understand.

I have tried writing the curl in so many different ways but nothing seems to work.

The curl from server 1:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"orderId":12345,"customerNr":98765}' \
https://returns.jdoe.blah.test/createReturn
```

The routing from web.php on server 2:

```
Route::post('/createReturn', 'ProductReturnsController@createReturn');
```

The method from the controller ProductReturnsController.php on server 2:

```
    public function createReturn($json)
    {
        echo "hallo\n";

        $jsonDecoded = json_decode($json);

        echo $jsonDecoded->orderId;

        print_r($jsonDecoded);

        //return view('data');
    }
```

I have the view commented out for now, as I want to make sure that I can send and receive a JSON object first.

The **output** after I run the curl in the command line is as follows:

```
>"<span class=sf-dump-str title="3 characters">120</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-686665084")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>REDIS_HOST</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-15249655 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="9 characters">127.0.0.1</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-15249655")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>REDIS_PASSWORD</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1240246613 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="4 characters">null</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1240246613")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>REDIS_PORT</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-2128112850 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="4 characters">6379</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-2128112850")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>MAIL_DRIVER</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-89924640 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="4 characters">smtp</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-89924640")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>MAIL_HOST</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-298105600 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="16 characters">smtp.mailtrap.io</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-298105600")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>MAIL_PORT</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1783830794 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="4 characters">2525</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1783830794")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>MAIL_USERNAME</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-18572966 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="4 characters">null</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-18572966")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>MAIL_PASSWORD</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1965143115 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="4 characters">null</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1965143115")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>MAIL_ENCRYPTION</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-384128930 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="4 characters">null</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-384128930")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1978382159 data-indent-pad="  ">""
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1978382159")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-593039413 data-indent-pad="  ">""
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-593039413")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>AWS_DEFAULT_REGION</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1272900874 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="9 characters">us-east-1</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1272900874")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>AWS_BUCKET</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1804584219 data-indent-pad="  ">""
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1804584219")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>PUSHER_APP_ID</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-95334387 data-indent-pad="  ">""
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-95334387")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>PUSHER_APP_KEY</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1487081807 data-indent-pad="  ">""
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1487081807")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>PUSHER_APP_SECRET</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1935165849 data-indent-pad="  ">""
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1935165849")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1333546276 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="3 characters">mt1</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1333546276")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1872466253 data-indent-pad="  ">""
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1872466253")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1866771313 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="3 characters">mt1</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1866771313")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>LDAP_USERNAME</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-2006453280 data-indent-pad="  ">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="18 characters">jdoe@ad.blah.de</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-2006453280")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                          <tr>
                <td>LDAP_PASSWORD</td>
                <td><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1985838971 data-indent-pad=" 
">"<span class=sf-dump-str title="10 characters">XXXXXXXXXX</span>"
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1985838971")</script>
</td>
              </tr>
                        </table>
              </div>
      </div>

    <div class="data-table-container" id="handlers">
    <label>Registered Handlers</label>
          <div class="handler active">
        0. Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler      </div>
      </div>

</div>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>var r=null;window.PR_SHOULD_USE_CONTINUATION=!0;
(function(){function O(a){function i(d){var a=d.charCodeAt(0);if(a!==92)return a;var f=d.charAt(1);return(a=s[f])?a:"0"<=f&&f<="7"?parseInt(d.substring(1),8):f==="u"||f==="x"?parseInt(d.substring(2),16):d.charCodeAt(1)}function g(d){if(d<32)return(d<16?"\\x0":"\\x")+d.toString(16);d=String.fromCharCode(d);return d==="\\"||d==="-"||d==="]"||d==="^"?"\\"+d:d}function j(d){var a=d.substring(1,d.length-1).match(/\\u[\dA-Fa-f]{4}|\\x[\dA-Fa-f]{2}|\\[0-3][0-7]{0,2}|\\[0-7]{1,2}|\\[\S\s]|[^\\]/g),d=[],f=
a[0]==="^",b=["["];f&&b.push("^");for(var f=f?1:0,c=a.length;f<c;++f){var i=this.attr("data-"+e.replace(m,"-$1").toLowerCase(),n);return null!==i?Y(i):t},val:function(t){return 0===arguments.length?this[0]&&(this[0].multiple?n(this[0]).find("option").filter(function(){return this.selected}).pluck("value"):this[0].value):this.each(function(e){this.value=J(this,t,e,this.value)})},offset:function(t){if(t)return this.each(function(e){var i=n(this),r=J(this,t,e,i.offset()),o=i.offsetParent().offset(),s={top:r.top-o.top,left:r.left-o.left};"static"==i.css("position")&&(s.position="relative"),i.css(s)});if(0==this.length)return null;var e=this[0].getBoundingClientRect();return{left:e.left+window.pageXOffset,top:e.top+window.pageYOffset,width:Math.round(e.width),height:Math.round(e.height)}},css:function(t,i){if(arguments.length<2){var r=this[0],o=getComputedStyle(r,"");if(!r)return;if("string"==typeof t)return r.style[C(t)]||o.getPropertyValue(t);if(A(t)){var s={};return n.each(A(t)?t:[t],function(t,e){s[e]=r.style[C(e)]||o.getPropertyValue(e)}),s}}var a="";if("string"==L(t))i||0===i?a=F(t)+":"+H(t,i):this.each(function(){this.style.removeProperty(F(t))});else for(e in t)t[e]||0===t[e]?a+=F(e)+":"+H(e,t[e])+";":this.each(function(){this.style.removeProperty(F(e))});return this.each(function(){this.style.cssText+=";"+a})},index:function(t){return t?this.indexOf(n(t)[0]):this.parent().children().indexOf(this[0])},hasClass:function(t){return t?r.some.call(this,function(t){return this.test(W(t))},q(t)):!1},addClass:function(t){return t?this.each(function(e){i=[];var r=W(this),o=J(this,t,e,r);o.split(/\s+/g).forEach(function(t){n(this).hasClass(t)||i.push(t)},this),i.length&&W(this,r+(r?" ":"")+i.join(" "))}):this},removeClass:function(e){return this.each(function(n){return e===t?W(this,""):(i=W(this),J(this,e,n,i).split(/\s+/g).forEach(function(t){i=i.replace(q(t)," ")}),void W(this,i.trim()))})},toggleClass:function(e,i){return e?this.each(function(r){var o=n(this),s=J(this,e,r,W(this));s.split(/\s+/g).forEach(function(e){(i===t?!o.hasClass(e):i)?o.addClass(e):o.removeClass(e)})}):this},scrollTop:function(e){if(this.length){var n="scrollTop"in this[0];return e===t?n?this[0].scrollTop:this[0].pageYOffset:this.each(n?function(){this.scrollTop=e}:function(){this.scrollTo(this.scrollX,e)})}},scrollLeft:function(e){if(this.length){var n="scrollLeft"in this[0];return e===t?n?this[0].scrollLeft:this[0].pageXOffset:this.each(n?function(){this.scrollLeft=e}:function(){this.scrollTo(e,this.scrollY)})}},position:function(){if(this.length){var t=this[0],e=this.offsetParent(),i=this.offset(),r=d.test(e[0].nodeName)?{top:0,left:0}:e.offset();return i.top-=parseFloat(n(t).css("margin-top"))||0,i.left-=parseFloat(n(t).css("margin-left"))||0,r.top+=parseFloat(n(e[0]).css("border-top-width"))||0,r.left+=parseFloat(n(e[0]).css("border-left-width"))||0,{top:i.top-r.top,left:i.left-r.left}}},offsetParent:function(){return this.map(function(){for(var t=this.offsetParent||a.body;t&&!d.test(t.nodeName)&&"static"==n(t).css("position");)t=t.offsetParent;return t})}},n.fn.detach=n.fn.remove,["width","height"].forEach(function(e){var i=e.replace(/./,function(t){return t[0].toUpperCase()});n.fn[e]=function(r){var o,s=this[0];return r===t?$(s)?s["inner"+i]:_(s)?s.documentElement["scroll"+i]:(o=this.offset())&&o[e]:this.each(function(t){s=n(this),s.css(e,J(this,r,t,s[e]()))})}}),v.forEach(function(t,e){var i=e%2;n.fn[t]=function(){var t,o,r=n.map(arguments,function(e){return t=L(e),"object"==t||"array"==t||null==e?e:S.fragment(e)}),s=this.length>1;return r.length<1?this:this.each(function(t,a){o=i?a:a.parentNode,a=0==e?a.nextSibling:1==e?a.firstChild:2==e?a:null,r.forEach(function(t){if(s)t=t.cloneNode(!0);else if(!o)return n(t).remove();G(o.insertBefore(t,a),function(t){null==t.nodeName||"SCRIPT"!==t.nodeName.toUpperCase()||t.type&&"text/javascript"!==t.type||t.src||window.eval.call(window,t.innerHTML)})})})},n.fn[i?t+"To":"insert"+(e?"Before":"After")]=function(e){return n(e)[t](this),this}}),S.Z.prototype=n.fn,S.uniq=N,S.deserializeValue=Y,n.zepto=S,n}();window.Zepto=Zepto,void 0===window.$&&(window.$=Zepto),function(t){function l(t){return t._zid||(t._zid=e++)}function h(t,e,n,i){if(e=p(e),e.ns)var r=d(e.ns);return(s[l(t)]||[]).filter(function(t){return!(!t||e.e&&t.e!=e.e||e.ns&&!r.test(t.ns)||n&&l(t.fn)!==l(n)||i&&t.sel!=i)})}function p(t){var e=(""+t).split(".");return{e:e[0],ns:e.slice(1).sort().join(" ")}}function d(t){return new RegExp("(?:^| )"+t.replace(" "," .* ?")+"(?: |$)")}function m(t,e){return t.del&&!u&&t.e in f||!!e}function g(t){return c[t]||u&&f[t]||t}function v(e,i,r,o,a,u,f){var h=l(e),d=s[h]||(s[h]=[]);i.split(/\s/).forEach(function(i){if("ready"==i)return t(document).ready(r);var s=p(i);s.fn=r,s.sel=a,s.e in c&&(r=function(e){var n=e.relatedTarget;return!n||n!==this&&!t.contains(this,n)?s.fn.apply(this,arguments):void 0}),s.del=u;var l=u||r;s.proxy=function(t){if(t=j(t),!t.isImmediatePropagationStopped()){t.data=o;var i=l.apply(e,t._args==n?[t]:[t].concat(t._args));return i===!1&&(t.preventDefault(),t.stopPropagation()),i}},s.i=d.length,d.push(s),"addEventListener"in e&&e.addEventListener(g(s.e),s.proxy,m(s,f))})}function y(t,e,n,i,r){var o=l(t);(e||"").split(/\s/).forEach(function(e){h(t,e,n,i).forEach(function(e){delete s[o][e.i],"removeEventListener"in t&&t.removeEventListener(g(e.e),e.proxy,m(e,r))})})}function j(e,i){return(i||!e.isDefaultPrevented)&&(i||(i=e),t.each(E,function(t,n){var r=i[t];e[t]=function(){return this[n]=x,r&&r.apply(i,arguments)},e[n]=b}),(i.defaultPrevented!==n?i.defaultPrevented:"returnValue"in i?i.returnValue===!1:i.getPreventDefault&&i.getPreventDefault())&&(e.isDefaultPrevented=x)),e}function T(t){var e,i={originalEvent:t};for(e in t)w.test(e)||t[e]===n||(i[e]=t[e]);return j(i,t)}var n,e=1,i=Array.prototype.slice,r=t.isFunction,o=function(t){return"string"==typeof t},s={},a={},u="onfocusin"in window,f={focus:"focusin",blur:"focusout"},c={mouseenter:"mouseover",mouseleave:"mouseout"};a.click=a.mousedown=a.mouseup=a.mousemove="MouseEvents",t.event={add:v,remove:y},t.proxy=function(e,n){if(r(e)){var i=function(){return e.apply(n,arguments)};return i._zid=l(e),i}if(o(n))return t.proxy(e[n],e);throw new TypeError("expected function")},t.fn.bind=function(t,e,n){return this.on(t,e,n)},t.fn.unbind=function(t,e){return this.off(t,e)},t.fn.one=function(t,e,n,i){return this.on(t,e,n,i,1)};var x=function(){return!0},b=function(){return!1},w=/^([A-Z]|returnValue$|layer[XY]$)/,E={preventDefault:"isDefaultPrevented",stopImmediatePropagation:"isImmediatePropagationStopped",stopPropagation:"isPropagationStopped"};t.fn.delegate=function(t,e,n){return this.on(e,t,n)},t.fn.undelegate=function(t,e,n){return this.off(e,t,n)},t.fn.live=function(e,n){return t(document.body).delegate(this.selector,e,n),this},t.fn.die=function(e,n){return t(document.body).undelegate(this.selector,e,n),this},t.fn.on=function(e,s,a,u,f){var c,l,h=this;return e&&!o(e)?(t.each(e,function(t,e){h.on(t,s,a,e,f)}),h):(o(s)||r(u)||u===!1||(u=a,a=s,s=n),(r(a)||a===!1)&&(u=a,a=n),u===!1&&(u=b),h.each(function(n,r){f&&(c=function(t){return y(r,t.type,u),u.apply(this,arguments)}),s&&(l=function(e){var n,o=t(e.target).closest(s,r).get(0);return o&&o!==r?(n=t.extend(T(e),{currentTarget:o,liveFired:r}),(c||u).apply(o,[n].concat(i.call(arguments,1)))):void 0}),v(r,e,u,a,s,l||c)}))},t.fn.off=function(e,i,s){var a=this;return e&&!o(e)?(t.each(e,function(t,e){a.off(t,i,e)}),a):(o(i)||r(s)||s===!1||(s=i,i=n),s===!1&&(s=b),a.each(function(){y(this,e,s,i)}))},t.fn.trigger=function(e,n){return e=o(e)||t.isPlainObject(e)?t.Event(e):j(e),e._args=n,this.each(function(){"dispatchEvent"in this?this.dispatchEvent(e):t(this).triggerHandler(e,n)})},t.fn.triggerHandler=function(e,n){var i,r;return this.each(function(s,a){i=T(o(e)?t.Event(e):e),i._args=n,i.target=a,t.each(h(a,e.type||e),function(t,e){return r=e.proxy(i),i.isImmediatePropagationStopped()?!1:void 0})}),r},"focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select keydown keypress keyup error".split(" ").forEach(function(e){t.fn[e]=function(t){return t?this.bind(e,t):this.trigger(e)}}),["focus","blur"].forEach(function(e){t.fn[e]=function(t){return t?this.bind(e,t):this.each(function(){try{this[e]()}catch(t){}}),this}}),t.Event=function(t,e){o(t)||(e=t,t=e.type);var n=document.createEvent(a[t]||"Events"),i=!0;if(e)for(var r in e)"bubbles"==r?i=!!e[r]:n[r]=e[r];return n.initEvent(t,i,!0),j(n)}}(Zepto),function(t){function l(e,n,i){var r=t.Event(n);return t(e).trigger(r,i),!r.isDefaultPrevented()}function h(t,e,i,r){return t.global?l(e||n,i,r):void 0}function p(e){e.global&&0===t.active++&&h(e,null,"ajaxStart")}function d(e){e.global&&!--t.active&&h(e,null,"ajaxStop")}function m(t,e){var n=e.context;return e.beforeSend.call(n,t,e)===!1||h(e,n,"ajaxBeforeSend",[t,e])===!1?!1:void h(e,n,"ajaxSend",[t,e])}function g(t,e,n,i){var r=n.context,o="success";n.success.call(r,t,o,e),i&&i.resolveWith(r,[t,o,e]),h(n,r,"ajaxSuccess",[e,n,t]),y(o,e,n)}function v(t,e,n,i,r){var o=i.context;i.error.call(o,n,e,t),r&&r.rejectWith(o,[n,e,t]),h(i,o,"ajaxError",[n,i,t||e]),y(e,n,i)}function y(t,e,n){var i=n.context;n.complete.call(i,e,t),h(n,i,"ajaxComplete",[e,n]),d(n)}function x(){}function b(t){return t&&(t=t.split(";",2)[0]),t&&(t==f?"html":t==u?"json":s.test(t)?"script":a.test(t)&&"xml")||"text"}function w(t,e){return""==e?t:(t+"&"+e).replace(/[&?]{1,2}/,"?")}function E(e){e.processData&&e.data&&"string"!=t.type(e.data)&&(e.data=t.param(e.data,e.traditional)),!e.data||e.type&&"GET"!=e.type.toUpperCase()||(e.url=w(e.url,e.data),e.data=void 0)}function j(e,n,i,r){return t.isFunction(n)&&(r=i,i=n,n=void 0),t.isFunction(i)||(r=i,i=void 0),{url:e,data:n,success:i,dataType:r}}function S(e,n,i,r){var o,s=t.isArray(n),a=t.isPlainObject(n);t.each(n,function(n,u){o=t.type(u),r&&(n=i?r:r+"["+(a||"object"==o||"array"==o?n:"")+"]"),!r&&s?e.add(u.name,u.value):"array"==o||!i&&"object"==o?S(e,u,i,n):e.add(n,u)})}var i,r,e=0,n=window.document,o=/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi,s=/^(?:text|application)\/javascript/i,a=/^(?:text|application)\/xml/i,u="application/json",f="text/html",c=/^\s*$/;t.active=0,t.ajaxJSONP=function(i,r){if(!("type"in i))return t.ajax(i);var f,h,o=i.jsonpCallback,s=(t.isFunction(o)?o():o)||"jsonp"+ ++e,a=n.createElement("script"),u=window[s],c=function(e){t(a).triggerHandler("error",e||"abort")},l={abort:c};return r&&r.promise(l),t(a).on("load error",function(e,n){clearTimeout(h),t(a).off().remove(),"error"!=e.type&&f?g(f[0],l,i,r):v(null,n||"error",l,i,r),window[s]=u,f&&t.isFunction(u)&&u(f[0]),u=f=void 0}),m(l,i)===!1?(c("abort"),l):(window[s]=function(){f=arguments},a.src=i.url.replace(/\?(.+)=\?/,"?$1="+s),n.head.appendChild(a),i.timeout>0&&(h=setTimeout(function(){c("timeout")},i.timeout)),l)},t.ajaxSettings={type:"GET",beforeSend:x,success:x,error:x,complete:x,context:null,global:!0,xhr:function(){return new window.XMLHttpRequest},accepts:{script:"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/x-javascript",json:u,xml:"application/xml, text/xml",html:f,text:"text/plain"},crossDomain:!1,timeout:0,processData:!0,cache:!0},t.ajax=function(e){var n=t.extend({},e||{}),o=t.Deferred&&t.Deferred();for(i in t.ajaxSettings)void 0===n[i]&&(n[i]=t.ajaxSettings[i]);p(n),n.crossDomain||(n.crossDomain=/^([\w-]+:)?\/\/([^\/]+)/.test(n.url)&&RegExp.$2!=window.location.host),n.url||(n.url=window.location.toString()),E(n),n.cache===!1&&(n.url=w(n.url,"_="+Date.now()));var s=n.dataType,a=/\?.+=\?/.test(n.url);if("jsonp"==s||a)return a||(n.url=w(n.url,n.jsonp?n.jsonp+"=?":n.jsonp===!1?"":"callback=?")),t.ajaxJSONP(n,o);var j,u=n.accepts[s],f={},l=function(t,e){f[t.toLowerCase()]=[t,e]},h=/^([\w-]+:)\/\//.test(n.url)?RegExp.$1:window.location.protocol,d=n.xhr(),y=d.setRequestHeader;if(o&&o.promise(d),n.crossDomain||l("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest"),l("Accept",u||"*/*"),(u=n.mimeType||u)&&(u.indexOf(",")>-1&&(u=u.split(",",2)[0]),d.overrideMimeType&&d.overrideMimeType(u)),(n.contentType||n.contentType!==!1&&n.data&&"GET"!=n.type.toUpperCase())&&l("Content-Type",n.contentType||"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),n.headers)for(r in n.headers)l(r,n.headers[r]);if(d.setRequestHeader=l,d.onreadystatechange=function(){if(4==d.readyState){d.onreadystatechange=x,clearTimeout(j);var e,i=!1;if(d.status>=200&&d.status<300||304==d.status||0==d.status&&"file:"==h){s=s||b(n.mimeType||d.getResponseHeader("content-type")),e=d.responseText;try{"script"==s?(1,eval)(e):"xml"==s?e=d.responseXML:"json"==s&&(e=c.test(e)?null:t.parseJSON(e))}catch(r){i=r}i?v(i,"parsererror",d,n,o):g(e,d,n,o)}else v(d.statusText||null,d.status?"error":"abort",d,n,o)}},m(d,n)===!1)return d.abort(),v(null,"abort",d,n,o),d;if(n.xhrFields)for(r in n.xhrFields)d[r]=n.xhrFields[r];var T="async"in n?n.async:!0;d.open(n.type,n.url,T,n.username,n.password);for(r in f)y.apply(d,f[r]);return n.timeout>0&&(j=setTimeout(function()e=e||[],t.extend(e,t.fn),e.selector=n||"",e.__Z=!0,e},isZ:function(e){return"array"===t.type(e)&&"__Z"in e}});try{getComputedStyle(void 0)}catch(e){var n=getComputedStyle;window.getComputedStyle=function(t){try{return n(t)}catch(e){return null}}}}(Zepto);
</script>
    <script>/*!
 * clipboard.js v1.5.3
 * https://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js
 *
 * Licensed MIT © Zeno Rocha
 */
    <script>Zepto(function($) {
  var $leftPanel      = $('.left-panel');
  var $frameContainer = $('.frames-container');
  var $appFramesTab   = $('#application-frames-tab');
  var $allFramesTab   = $('#all-frames-tab');
  var $container      = $('.details-container');
  var $activeLine     = $frameContainer.find('.frame.active');
  var $activeFrame    = $container.find('.frame-code.active');
  var $ajaxEditors    = $('.editor-link[data-ajax]');
  var $header         = $('header');

  $header.on('mouseenter', function () {
    if ($header.find('.exception').height() >= 145) {
      $header.addClass('header-expand');
    }
  });
  $header.on('mouseleave', function () {
    $header.removeClass('header-expand');
  });

  /*
   * add prettyprint classes to our current active codeblock
   * run prettyPrint() to highlight the active code
   * scroll to the line when prettyprint is done
   * highlight the current line
   */
  var renderCurrentCodeblock = function(id) {

    // remove previous codeblocks so we only render the active one
    $('.code-block').removeClass('prettyprint');

    // pass the id in when we can for speed
    if (typeof(id) === 'undefined' || typeof(id) === 'object') {
      var id = /frame\-line\-([\d]*)/.exec($activeLine.attr('id'))[1];
    }

    $('#frame-code-linenums-' + id).addClass('prettyprint');
    $('#frame-code-args-' + id).addClass('prettyprint');

    prettyPrint(highlightCurrentLine);

  }

  /*
   * Highlight the active and neighboring lines for the current frame
   * Adjust the offset to make sure that line is veritcally centered
   */

  var highlightCurrentLine = function() {
    var activeLineNumber = +($activeLine.find('.frame-line').text());
    var $lines           = $activeFrame.find('.linenums li');
    var firstLine        = +($lines.first().val());

    // We show more code than needed, purely for proper syntax highlighting
    // Let’s hide a big chunk of that code and then scroll the remaining block
    $activeFrame.find('.code-block').first().css({
      maxHeight: 345,
      overflow: 'hidden',
    });

    var $offset = $($lines[activeLineNumber - firstLine - 10]);
    if ($offset.length > 0) {
      $offset[0].scrollIntoView();
    }

    $($lines[activeLineNumber - firstLine - 1]).addClass('current');
    $($lines[activeLineNumber - firstLine]).addClass('current active');
    $($lines[activeLineNumber - firstLine + 1]).addClass('current');

    $container.scrollTop(0);

  }

  /*
   * click handler for loading codeblocks
   */

  $frameContainer.on('click', '.frame', function() {

    var $this  = $(this);
    var id     = /frame\-line\-([\d]*)/.exec($this.attr('id'))[1];
    var $codeFrame = $('#frame-code-' + id);

    if ($codeFrame) {

      $activeLine.removeClass('active');
      $activeFrame.removeClass('active');

      $this.addClass('active');
      $codeFrame.addClass('active');

      $activeLine  = $this;
      $activeFrame = $codeFrame;

      renderCurrentCodeblock(id);

    }

  });

  var clipboard = new Clipboard('.clipboard');
  var showTooltip = function(elem, msg) {
    elem.setAttribute('class', 'clipboard tooltipped tooltipped-s');
    elem.setAttribute('aria-label', msg);
  };

  clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
      e.clearSelection();

      showTooltip(e.trigger, 'Copied!');
  });

  clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
      showTooltip(e.trigger, fallbackMessage(e.action));
  });

  var btn = document.querySelector('.clipboard');

  btn.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
    e.currentTarget.setAttribute('class', 'clipboard');
    e.currentTarget.removeAttribute('aria-label');
  });

  function fallbackMessage(action) {
    var actionMsg = '';
    var actionKey = (action === 'cut' ? 'X' : 'C');

    if (/Mac/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        actionMsg = 'Press ⌘-' + actionKey + ' to ' + action;
    } else {
        actionMsg = 'Press Ctrl-' + actionKey + ' to ' + action;
    }

    return actionMsg;
  }

  function scrollIntoView($node, $parent) {
    var nodeOffset = $node.offset();
    var nodeTop = nodeOffset.top;
    var nodeBottom = nodeTop + nodeOffset.height;
    var parentScrollTop = $parent.scrollTop();
    var parentHeight = $parent.height();

    if (nodeTop < 0) {
      $parent.scrollTop(parentScrollTop + nodeTop);
    } else if (nodeBottom > parentHeight) {
      $parent.scrollTop(parentScrollTop + nodeBottom - parentHeight);
    }
  }

  $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    var applicationFrames = $frameContainer.hasClass('frames-container-application'),
        frameClass = applicationFrames ? '.frame.frame-application' : '.frame';

      if(e.ctrlKey || e.which === 74  || e.which === 75) {
          // CTRL+Arrow-UP/k and Arrow-Down/j support:
          // 1) select the next/prev element
          // 2) make sure the newly selected element is within the view-scope
          // 3) focus the (right) container, so arrow-up/down (without ctrl) scroll the details
          if (e.which === 38 /* arrow up */ || e.which === 75 /* k */) {
              $activeLine.prev(frameClass).click();
              scrollIntoView($activeLine, $leftPanel);
              $container.focus();
              e.preventDefault();
          } else if (e.which === 40 /* arrow down */ || e.which === 74 /* j */) {
              $activeLine.next(frameClass).click();
              scrollIntoView($activeLine, $leftPanel);
              $container.focus();
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      } else if (e.which == 78 /* n */) {
      if ($appFramesTab.length) {
        setActiveFramesTab($('.frames-tab:not(.frames-tab-active)'));
      }
    }
  });

  // Render late enough for highlightCurrentLine to be ready
  renderCurrentCodeblock();

  // Avoid to quit the page with some protocol (e.g. IntelliJ Platform REST API)
  $ajaxEditors.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get(this.href);
  });

  // Symfony VarDumper: Close the by default expanded objects
  $('.sf-dump-expanded')
    .removeClass('sf-dump-expanded')
    .addClass('sf-dump-compact');
  $('.sf-dump-toggle span').html('&#9654;');

  // Make the given frames-tab active
  function setActiveFramesTab($tab) {
    $tab.addClass('frames-tab-active');

    if ($tab.attr('id') == 'application-frames-tab') {
      $frameContainer.addClass('frames-container-application');
      $allFramesTab.removeClass('frames-tab-active');
    } else {
      $frameContainer.removeClass('frames-container-application');
      $appFramesTab.removeClass('frames-tab-active');
    }
  }

  $('a.frames-tab').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setActiveFramesTab($(this));
  });
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As I am passing orderId, I am expecting to see "12345", when I echo the orderId.

Please can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
When I run the following, and I don't decode the JSON in createReturn, it prints "hallo" in the console as expected:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"orderId":12345,"customerNr":98765}' \
https://returns.jdoe.blah.test/createReturn
```

However, when I run the above curl and try to decode the JSON in createReturn, it prints the whole html file as mentioned above. So it seems to have something to do with the JSON decoding, maybe?

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but have you checked that you aren't ```dump```-ing your ```.env``` earlier in the request cycle? I see that the data has the ```sf-dump``` classes and such, which to my knowledge comes from using the symfony ```dump``` command, not ```print_r```. In short, are you actually seeing the script print your ```echo "hallo\n";``` line?

Comment: @Kyrre How do I know if I am dumping the .env file earlier in the request cycle? It sounds stupid, but as far as I am aware, I am calling the uri /createReturn, which goes into my controller ProductReturnsController which then calls the function createReturn, where all it should do is echo "hallo".

Comment: @Kyrre Also, I just removed the json object and ran: curl -X POST https://returns.jdoe.blah.test/createReturn and it gave me the whole html file again. But yesterday when I ran the command without the JSON object it worked and printed "hello". I have no idea why it has changed.

Comment: I would do a project wide search for the ```dump``` function, and start working my way through the request, starting from ```ìndex.php``` (or ```{app/app_dev}.php``` depending on your Symfony version). Other than that, I'm sorry that I can't be more helpful.. Don't know the ins and outs of curl >_>

Comment: @Kyrre Thanks :). I will go ahead and do a project wide search now. Btw, I just tried curl https://returns.jdoe.blah.test/createReturn without GET or POST and it printed "hallo", as expected. I have no idea why POST isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong :).

I changed my curl to:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" \
--data '{"orderId":"12345", "customerNr":"98765"}' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST https://returns.jdoe.blah.test/createReturn
```

I edited my method in ProductReturnsController.php to:

```
    public function createReturn(Request $request)
    {
        $arr = $request->all();

        foreach ($arr as $value){
            echo "Current value is: " . $value . "\n";
        }
    }
```

My problem was that I was just using $json as a parameter, but I needed to type-hint the parameter using Request $request and then accessing $request in order to get the information stored in the JSON object.

If I only wanted to access orderId for example, as I attempted in my question above, I could have used **input()** instead of **all()**:

```
    public function createReturn(Request $request)
    {
        $orderId = $request->input('orderId');

        echo "The order id is: " . $orderId . "\n";
    }
```

Hopefully this can help someone else, if they come across the same problem.